# Getting the value of the changed property related to an Observer

Tags: objective-c

I've got an observer on my textFields which looks to see if the "enabled@ property has changed.

```
 (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *) context;
{


UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)object;




BOOL new = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
BOOL old = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] boolValue];


if ((new != old) && (new = YES))
{

 [self fadeDisable:txtField];
}

else if ((new != old) && (new = NO))
{
    [self fadeEnable:txtField];

}
```

I thought if I used int new and int old, the 1 or 0 which defined if the property is enabled or not would be returned but when I use NSLog to see what thy are bringing back, it's a long string of numbers.

I looked through the documentation and it seems that objectForKey actually return an id not an integer but i'm not sure what to do.

Edit: i've added the code for my comparison which is trying to determine if it went from disabled to enabled (or vice versa). Also added the boolValue correction as recommended.

It does not give the intended result and doesn't call the correct method. Is it correct?
Thanks

Comment: ***int new*** ??? Do you think it will compile?

Comment: They're `id`, because dictionaries can contain objects only. If the original property is an `int`, then chances are you are getting `NSNumber`s back.

Comment: @LithuT.V Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it did compile. So how can I get something useful? use valueForKey or something like that?

Comment: seems like you should replace (new = YES) with (new == YES). Or (YES == new), read about "Yoda expressions" :). The same with (new = NO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary` contains objects (like `NSNumber`), not primitive types (like `int`). As you have noticed,

```
[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]
```

returns `id`. If you want to convert it to int, use

```
int new = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] intValue]
```

Or if the property is a BOOL, even better:

```
BOOL new = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue]
```

This line of code

```
int new = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]
```

results in storing value of pointer to the `NSNumber` object into `new` integer, this is the "long string of numbers" you mentioned. Strangely, it does compile without even a warning.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did as you instructed, makes sense. I've added code in my original questiopn for a comparison i'm doing but does not seem to be working. Could you please help with that?